# How to install Octave in OS X 10.9

Tags: macos

I had previously used macports to install octave. It was working fine after switching to 10.9, but after the upgrade I tried to add a different package and it did not work. So I foolishly followed the instructions to delete and reinstall everything, and now octave will not reinstall!

I don't care how I get octave on my computer. I just really really need a working copy of it for this weekend. Any suggestions (for a beginner) would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Homebrew for installing octave.
I find homebrew more clean and less intrusion than macports as it uses the system libraries available if possible.

Following the instructions on [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Simple_Installation_Instructions_3)

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install octave --without-docs
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I did the same thing... I'd be stoked to see a solution to this. 
Have you tried installing `octave-devel` instead?

```
sudo port install octave-devel +atlas+docs+gcc48
```

Maybe this will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed see this [bug ticket](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/41211)

Please do:

```
sudo port clean octave
sudo port selfupdate
```

and then try installing it again.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this download from SourceForge:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/